# Spring-boot folder structure

Tags: spring

I'm starting writing a Spring/boot Angular 4 application and I have a small question. In the Angular 4 app we create a folder called `LocalEvent` (or something) which houses the module, controller, service, html template and css file. How would I create a structure for Spring?

I've seen Spring folder examples where everything is divided into /services /controllers. I understand that Java uses packages, so having 10 folders would mean having 10 packages which could get confusing fast. But I would like to hear from a few more experienced developers how they set up their Spring structure.

Comment: 10 packages should not confuse you. I mean, the standard Java API alone has hundreds of them. Spring too. Why would 10 packages be confusing?

Comment: So you're saying I could do the same structure as the Angular 2 styleguide? Every component has it's own folder?

Comment: There is no "component" in Spring boot. So I'm not sure what you're talking about. But the usual way of splitting code in packages is either by technical domain, then functional domain, or the reverse.

Comment: You can use as many packages you want but I'ts more cleaner and simplir to break down your code into small services. frontendServiceA, frontendServiceB, frontendServiceC built with Angular.js. Then your back-end with Spring(boot). Small services that use  HTTP or JSON to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Spring Boot structure as far as I know. The service and controller packages structure are the way how Java programmers architect their applications following the popular MVC pattern. Next, there is a Maven standard  project structure where other Java or JVM based languages build tools follow